What is the source for this urban fantasy quote comparing the supernatural world to the insect world?
I had been browsing TV Tropes when I came across this very interesting quote from an urban fantasy or paranormal romance story that stuck with me. The quote went something along the lines of..."the [magical world] wasn't like the natural world. It was more like the insect world, where horrible creatures did unspeakable things to each other in the dark". I distinctly remember the comparison to insects as well as the word "unspeakable".
I've been trying to relocate the quote but I can't seem to find it. All I remember is that it came from a series kind of similar to Kelly Armstrong's Women of the Otherworld series, Seanan McGuire's October Daye, or Lost Girl. Yet I'm not sure if it comes from any of these works specifically, as I cannot find a quote for them when I search their TV Tropes page. I tried searching TV Tropes for variants of this quotes but couldn't find anything. Does anyone know where this quote came from?

I don't recognize the quote specifically, but it sounds similar to descriptions in the "Laundry Files" series of novels (and a few short stories) by Charles Stross.

Can't find the quote, it does sound like Charlie's work but also not quite, my first thought was that it was Simon R. Green, either the Nightside though I don't recognise it or the secret Histories in which case I wouldn't know it.

In one of Terry Pratchett’s books about the witches he makes a comparison between faeries and insects.

If it's possible you're not recalling it exactly right, there's a similar quote from a Buffy/Stargate crossover fan-fic called "Return to Normal:"

It didn’t happen often. O’Neill believed in strength through firepower, so was rarely caught without a weapon. It was just Buffy’s luck that she had been a witness to it on one of the extremely rare occasions when Jack had been forced to use his hands. She’d almost thrown up afterwards. It wasn’t like two great jungle beasts doing battle, or honorable Japanese samurai settling their dispute the old-fashioned way. The closest comparison she could come up with was the insect world, where ambush predators did inhumanly disgusting things to their prey. She’d never forgotten what she’d seen that day. Jack O’Neill was far closer to being a praying mantis than he was to being a civilized human being.

It's quoted on the TVTropes page "Screw the Rules, They're Not Real!."
